# Converting SQL Data to List of generic

Tags: c#, generics, sqldatareader

I have a table full of strings I need to convert it to a list of generic object with types. What I have so far.

```
private List<T> ConvertDataToObject<T>(object oClass, string sSQL)
{
    List<T> lReturn = new List<T>();
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString);
    SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sSQL.ToString());
    sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
    try
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataReader sqlDR = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlDR.Read())
        {
            foreach (var prop in oClass.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (prop.Name == sqlDR[prop.Name])
                { 
                    prop.SetValue(oClass, Convert.ChangeType(sqlDR[prop.Name].ToString().Trim().Replace("'", "''"), prop.PropertyType), null); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
    finally
    { sqlCon.Close(); }

    return lReturn;
}
```

I don't think this is correct: 
1: I need to fill the list with the object and I am not sure how I want to do that
2: I am not sure that the 2 loops is the best way to fill in the object.

Comment: this may help:
http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2015/09/implementing-repository-pattern-and.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a class to map DB query results to objects in the past.  The only "gotcha" in this implementation is that the SQL column name needs to match the property name of the class.

Here is the class:

```
public class DataObjectMapper<T> where T : new()
{
    public List<T> MapResultsToObject(IDataReader reader)
    {
        List<T> objects = new List<T>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            objects.Add(MapRow(reader));
        }

        return objects;
    }

    private T MapRow(IDataReader reader)
    {
        T item = new T();

        var typeProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in typeProperties)
        {
            int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal(property.Name);

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
            {
                property.SetValue(item, reader[ordinal].ToString(), null);
            }
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

And here's how it's used

```
   DataObjectMapper<T> resultsMapper = new DataObjectMapper<T>();

   SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

   List<T> results = resultsMapper.MapResultsToObject(reader);
```

Comment: This seems like it will work but I am getting an error "'T' must be a non abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method"

Comment: Its working thank you:
private List<T> ConvertDataToObject<T>(object oClass, string sSQL) where T : new()